# post data based on the number of users

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I want to ask, I want to post notification data but based on the number of existing users. I've tried like this but only post 1 data, while there are 2 user data, please help.

```
$acc = $registrant->update([
                'approval' => 1,
                'description' => $request->description,
            ]);

            $notification = new Notification();
            $roleuser = User::where('is_admin', 4)->orWhere('is_admin', '3')->get();
            foreach ($roleuser as $key => $value) {
                $notification->user_id = $value->id;
                $notification->type = 'Menunggu Pelatihan';
                $notification->title = 'Pendaftar menunggu untuk pelatihan';
                $notification->message = "halo " . $value->name . " Pendaftar dengan NIP " . $registrant->nip . " menunggu untuk pelatihan";
                $notification->save();
            }
```

Comment: are you sure $roleuser has 2 data? can you post a dd of the variable?

Comment: Perhaps `$notification = new Notification();` would rather belong into the loop?